# How to force input type="date" to display in mm-dd-yyyy format?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

In a React project, I'm displaying date in normal form i.e dd/mm/yyyy since its based on browser location settings, but, I need it in mm/dd/yyyy format based on english date. Is there any way to enforce it to display it in that required format.

```
const DateComp = () => {
  var newDateValue = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0];

  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(newDateValue);
  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="date"
        required
        className="form-control cpselect box-shadow"
        defaultValue={selectedDate}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default DateComp;
```

Here input type="date" accepts only toISOString(), but, it shows date only in dd/mm/yyyy format whereas I'm expecting it to format in mm/dd/yyyy. What could be best solution?

Comment: You cannot override the [standard behaviour](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date). You will need to create a custom component to imitate the interaction. For example, you can create a text input that overlays the actual date input, and format and set the date input value into text input so that it looks how you want it to.

Comment: If possible can you implement? I tried with all solutions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to change input type="date" format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker

Answer (score 0):

Use **react-date-picker** package.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import DatePicker from 'react-date-picker';

function MyApp() {
  const [value, onChange] = useState(new Date());

  return (
    <div>
      <DatePicker onChange={onChange} value={value} format="MM-dd-y" />
    </div>
  );
}
```